# Adequate Trial Size Calculation.

Tags: statistics

Firstly, thanks for answering my last question. I appreciate the help and effort put in.

I have another question to put forth. Again, it is related to Medical Statistics.

There are one third of male prisoners who have a history of heroin injection. One in $200$ of them will die from heroin overdose. To prevent plausibly $30\%$ of these deaths, a major trial will randomize individuals to control and intervention.

And we need to calculate how many consented prisoners need to be randomized for the proposed trial to have $80\%$ power to discern a $30\%$ reduction in heroin overdoses within $4$ weeks of release for prisoners.

What I have been taught is to do something like this:

Target reduction is $30\%$. Initial ratio to start with is $0.5\%$ and have to go to $0.35\%$.

So, $(0.5\cdot99.5)+(0.35\cdot99.65)$ and divide this by $30^2$ to get the value of $n$, i.e., the number in each group that should be taken to conduct the test.

The value of $n$ is coming out to be $0.009$ something, which I think is wrong. Am I reading the question wrong? How else can I do this question?

Thank you very much again!